# Accessing to PK in Function Based View in a Template Context Processor

Tags: python, django

Im building a Template Context Processor to call the PK of each page that I have and that PK call it in the base.html, I have achieve to do a Template Context Processor with other query, but now I need to pass the PK. The context `p` works very well, but the context `edit` it does not, how can I call the PK from a Function Based View?

For example: localhost:8000/path/8 , I need to pass 8 in the context `edit`

```
  def my_processor(request):
        context = {'edit':InfoPredioGeneral.objects.filter(pk=self.kwargs['pk']),
                   'p':InfoPredioGeneral.objects.filter(user_id=request.user).latest('id')}
        return context
```

I know that it does not works because of `self` and `kwargs` are not defined. But how can I do that?

Comment: You are trying to use `pk=self.kwargs['pk']` when you haven't defined `self`

Comment: @Hybrid Thanks.. And sorry for the question, Im newbie in Django, how can I define `self`?

Comment: you don't, self is only used for classes. the kwargs dict is part of the request.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using a FBV instead of a CBV, so the **self** you are using should be used with class methods, answering your question, you should pass the **id** parameter in the view, do something like this:

```
def my_processor(request, id):
    context = {'edit':InfoPredioGeneral.objects.filter(pk=id),
               'p':InfoPredioGeneral.objects.filter(user_id=request.user).latest('id')}
    return context
```

in your urls.py you should put something like this:

```
url(r'^path/(?P<id>\d+)', my_processor, name='my_processor')
```